# String isn't insert into table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I attached my php code below, and I have one question for you, why the query doesn't execute when I try to insert a new user into the table? I mention that I get succes_set, that means the insert_stmt->execute() runs correctly.

```
if($_SESSION["err_set"] == 0)
{
    $password = hash('whirlpool', $password);
$password = strtoupper($password);
    $created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if($insert_stmt == $db_link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email, password, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) 
{
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $first_name, $last_name, $username, $email, $password, $created);
        if (!$insert_stmt->execute()) 
        {
            $_SESSION["err_set"] = 1;
            $_SESSION["err_txt"] = "Unknown error, code: 1301";
            header('Location: ../index.php?page=register&lang='.$language);
        }
    }
    $_SESSION["succes_set"] = 1;
    header('Location: ../index.php?page=login&lang='.$language);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that, I removed one of the "=" character from

```
$insert_stmt == $db_link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email, password, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
```

and now I have

```
$insert_stmt = $db_link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, email, password, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
```

Thank you, guys.